# Allow argument/option to override positional argument

Tags: python, argparse

I am trying to make exclusion in my `argparse` parser. Basically what I want is to avoid `--all` option and `filenames` argument to be parsed (which I think succeeded).

But I want to create also another check where if I only pass `python reader.py read --all`, the `filenames` argument will get populated with all txt files in current directory.

So far I've come up with following code:

```
import argparse
import glob

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
subcommands = parser.add_subparsers(title='subcommands')

read_command = subcommands.add_parser('read')
read_command.add_argument('filenames', type=argparse.FileType(), nargs = '+')
read_command.add_argument('-a', '--all', action='store_true')

parsed = parser.parse_args()

if parsed.all and parsed.filenames:
    raise SystemExit

if parsed.all:
    parsed.filenames = glob.glob('*.txt')

print parsed
```

The problem is that if I try to run `python reader.py read --all` I get error `error: too few arguments` because of the `filenames` argument.

1. Is there a way to have this work like I want to without creating subcommand to `read`, for example `python reader.py read all`?
2. How can I access error messages in `argparse`? I'd like to have some default message that would say that `filenames` and `--all` can't be combined instead of `SystemExit` error.

Also I want to avoid using `add_mutually_exclusive_group` because this is just a snippet of my real parser where this approach wouldn't work (already checked in other SO topic).

I've heard about custom actions but it would really help to see example on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `filenames` gets `nargs="*"`, it should allow you to use `--all` alone.  `parsed.filenames` will then be a `[]`, which you can replace with the `glob`.

You could also test giving that argument a `default` derived from the `glob` - but see my caution regarding `FileType`.

Do you want the parser to open all the filenames you give it?  Or would you rather open the files latter yourself (preferably in a `with` context).  `FileType` opens the files (creating if necessary), and in the process checks their existence (which is nice), but leaves it up to you (or the program exit) to close them.

The documentation talks about issuing error messages yourself, and how to change them.  `parser.error('my message')` with display the usage and message, and then exit.

```
if parsed.all and parsed.filenames:
    parsed.error("Do you want to read ALL or just %s?"%parsed.filenames)
```

It is also possible trap `SystemExit` exceptions in a `try/except` clause.